# How Drag & Drop Builder save current selected widget/component state?

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop

I know this might be a noob question. Let's say an email template builder for example. When you drag and drop say an image widget to the builder area and then you click the image which then reveals some settings to customize the image selected.

My question is, where is the ID/reference of the selected image stored such that any settings made applies to that image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Please post what you have tried.  As it stands this is likely overly broad in scope.

Comment: I have tried saving the state or ID to window object. But I feel it's not the right way. Curious to see what others are doing.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+build+a+drag+and+drop+html+javascript&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS784US784&oq=how+to+build+a+drag+and+drop+html+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.11018j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't mean to be rude but apparently you do not understand my question. I know how to make a drag and drop stuff. If you do not understand my question, ask for clarification.

Comment: Not to come across as rude either I was merely pointing out that your question lacks according to site guidelines which I referenced to help you.  This is a coding site and code is expected in questions.  To make it a better question you should (have) posted the actual code you were trying to use and fix.  To be honest, I am going to post an answer (because creating a simple example was super easy) but also voting to close this question due to that lack of a set of viable code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was super easy to do, I did a super quick mockup with a minimal viable example copied directly from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop

I then modified it to be an `img` not a `div` and put in a console log to show the `img` properties including the id and anything else it has.

```js
var dragged;

/* events fired on the draggable target */
document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {

}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  // store a ref. on the dragged elem
  dragged = event.target;
  // make it half transparent
  event.target.style.opacity = .5;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  // reset the transparency
  event.target.style.opacity = "";
}, false);

/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
  // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "purple";
  }

}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
  // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
  }

}, false);

document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
console.log(dragged);
  // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
  event.preventDefault();
  // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
    dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
    event.target.appendChild(dragged);
  }

}, false);
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.dropzone {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blueviolet;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
  <img id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)" alt="draggableimg" />

</div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```